# Почему сдвигается input в IE11?

Tags: html, css, ie11

В IE11 получается вот так http://prntscr.com/r8uemz .Когда input в фокусе и появляется список, он по какой-то причине сдвигается...

````
                                <label class="order-registration__label"><sup>*</sup>Населенный пункт</label>
                                <input type="text" class="city-input" id="input-city">
                                <div class="order-registration__list">
                                    <label class="order-registration__list-label"><input type="radio" name="city" class="order-registration__list-input" value="г. Орехово-Зуево 1, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл." checked>г. Орехово-Зуево 1, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл.</label>
                                    <label class="order-registration__list-label"><input class="order-registration__list-input" name="city" type="text" value="г. Москва">г. Москва</label>
                                    <label class="order-registration__list-label"><input type="radio" name="city" class="order-registration__list-input" value="г. Орехово-Зуево 2, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл.">г. Орехово-Зуево 2, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл.</label>
                                    <label class="order-registration__list-label"><input type="radio" name="city" class="order-registration__list-input" value="г. Орехово-Зуево 3, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл.">г. Орехово-Зуево 3, д. Абрамовка, тер. СНТ Москва, Московская обл.</label>
                                </div>```
````

Comment: Экстрасенсов тут не много. CSS увидеть не помешает. А вообще, в ие11 тоже есть инспектор, его можно открыть и покрутить стили прям там. Посмотреть что на это влияет будет не сложно.

Comment: Если не покрутила, сюда бы вопрос не писала. Пишу, потому что все попробовала, все покрутила. Дело в скролле, из-за него он отодвигается